# Print Bitmap to ESC/POS printer

Tags: printing, thermal-printer

I am trying to print to a ESC/POS compatible printer and am struggling to get my head around `GS v 0`. I have just connected from a Mac and sending commands is `hex` via CoolTerm.

The docs say ...

```
  GS v 0 m xL xH yL yH d1....dk
  -----------------------------------------------------
  [Name] Print raster bit image
  [Format] ASCII GS v 0 m xL xH yL yH d1....dk
  Hex 1D 76 30 m xL xH yL yH d1....dk
  Decimal 29 118 48 m xL xH yL yH d1....dk
  [Range] 0≤xL≤48, xH=0; 0≤yL≤255, yH=0; 0≤d≤255
  k=(xL+xH×256)×(yL+yH×256)(k≠0)
  [Description] Selects Raster bit-image mode. The value of m selects the mode, as follows:
+------+------------+----------------------------+---------------------------+
|  m   |    MODE    |      Vertical Dot Density  |  Horizontal Dot density   |
+------+------------+----------------------------+---------------------------+
|0, 48 |   Normal   |          200 DPI           |        200 DPI            |
+------+------------+----------------------------+---------------------------+
|1, 49 |Double-width|          200 DPI           |        100 DPI            |
+------+-------------+---------------------------+---------------------------+
|2, 50 |Double-height|         100 DPI           |        200 DPI            |
+------+-------------+---------------------------+---------------------------+
|3, 51 | Quadruple  |          100 DPI           |        100 DPI            |
+------+-------------+---------------------------+---------------------------+

 • xL, xH, select the number of data bits ( xL+ xH × 256) in the horizontal direction for the bit image.
 • yL, yH, select the number of data bits ( yL+ yH × 256) in the vertical direction for the bit image.
 • This command has no effect in all print modes (character size, emphasized, double-strike, upside-down, underline, white/black reverse printing, etc.) for raster bit image.
 • The part of bit image that exceeds the printable area will not be printed.
 • d indicates the bit-image data. Set time a bit to 1 prints a dot and setting it to 0 does not print a dot.
```

So from this I deduce I need to send the following in `HEX`

```
 1D 76 30 30 20 00 00 01
```

Does the image data now follow this, and do I have to send a message saying the image has ended?

Answer (score 0):

I remember there is `<ESC>K` (not GS) command to print 8 lines of pixels. See ESC commands for details. After K must be sent 2 bytes - number of data bytes and the real data. But it is not guaranteed whether every printer will support this. What is the brand and model of your?

Answer (score 0):

The [docs](https://reference.epson-biz.com/modules/ref_escpos/index.php?content_id=94) say:

```
Hex 1D 76 30 m xL xH yL yH d1....dk
```

with `m` being 0x48..0x51, so you can't send

```
1D 76 30 30 20 00 00 01
```

but rather, for instance

```
1D 76 30 48 20 00 00 01
```

I don't think it makes much sense that `xH` and `yL` are 0.